# elisp: Handling wrong-type-argument exception

Tags: lisp, elisp

I want to kill all buffers visiting a file in a given directory, keeping all others.  However, my function bombs out when it reaches the `#<buffer  *Minibuf-1*>`; the minibuffer isn't visiting a file.

```lisp
(defun my-kill-all-visiting-buffers (dir)
  "Kill all buffers visiting DIR."
  (interactive)
  (mapcar
   (lambda (buf)
     (and (string-match-p
           (regexp-quote dir)
           (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name buf)))
         (kill-buffer buf)))
   (buffer-list)))
```

In Python-land, I would ask for forgiveness and wrap it in a `try-except`.  How would I handle this in the land of lisp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the exception with something like `condition-case` which elisp has.  Or you could just do something like this (avoiding the regexp-quotery as well):

```
    (defun my-kill-all-visiting-buffers (dir)
  "Kill all buffers visiting DIR or any subdirectory of DIR"
  (interactive "Ddirectory: ")
  (mapc
   (lambda (buf)
     (let ((bfn (buffer-file-name buf)))
       (when (and (not (null bfn))
                  (file-in-directory-p bfn dir))
         (kill-buffer buf))))
   (buffer-list)))
```

There are probably better approaches.

---

### Notes

`(not (null x))` is the same as `x` but I use it intentionally so when I read it I know I am checking for `x` not being a conceptually void value, rather than it just being false.

This avoids regexp operations (originally `string=` now `string-prefix-p`), because, famously:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Instead it uses `file-in-directory-p` which asks exactly the question it wants the answer to: is `file` in a directory or any subdirectory of `dir`? (Thanks to Stefan for this, which I didn't know about.)

All of the above is legal in Emacs 26.2: I don't keep track of which things in elisp changed & arrived when any more.

Elisp is not that close to many other dialects of Lisp in use other than rather superficially: techniques which are used in elisp may or may not apply to other languages in the family but often don't.

Comment: I think you want to use `string-prefix-p` rather than `string=` in case `bfn` is inside a subdirectory of `dir`.

Comment: @Stefan: I assumed they wanted buffers in the directory exactly: which they want is up to them, obviously!

Comment: Of course, but the original code goes through the trouble of using `regexp-quote`+`string-match-p` presumably because `string=` wasn't what they wanted ;-)

Comment: @Stefan: you're right.  I was reacting to the regexps.  I've changed it now! (Note also that `string-match-p` as originally used was dangerous because `(string-match-p (rexexp-quote "/tmp") "/home/x/foo/tmp")` is true.

Comment: Indeed the regexp code was flawed, but I thought its intention was clear ;-)  BTW, after reading your new text I was reminded that we do have a corresponding explicit operation filenames: `file-in-directory-p`!

Comment: @Stefan: doh, I didn't know about that.  I've changed it to use that now.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW, regarding "changed & arrived when", in Emacs-27 the `*Help*` buffers for vars and functions include a guess (based on a quick etc/NEWS perusal) of when it was introduced ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found that it wasn't necessary to catch *all* possible errors.  Handling the case where a buffer is not associated with a file is sufficient.

The use of `regexp-quote` is used to handle closing files in subdirectories.

```lisp
(defun my-kill-all-visiting-buffers (dir)
  "Kill all buffers visiting DIR."
  (interactive)
  (mapcar
   (lambda (buf)
     (let ((bfn (buffer-file-name buf)))
       (and (not (null bfn))
            (string-match-p (regexp-quote dir) (file-name-directory bfn))
            (kill-buffer buf))))
   (buffer-list)))
```